# How does the voltage across a capacitor relate to the voltage across a resistor in an $RC$ circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

So I know that in an $RC$ circuit
$v = R\frac{dQ}{dt} + \frac{Q}{C}$

with voltage*v* and resistance and capacitance *R* and *C*, respectively.

$\implies$ *Q* = $vC(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})$

Therefore the voltage across the capacitor is given by:
$$v_C =v(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})$$

Since the voltage across the resistor($v_R$) = $R\frac{dQ}{dt}$

does this imply the equation below is true?

$v_r =RC\frac{d}{dt}(v_c)$

Comment: Have you been exposed to A/C circuits?

Comment: Yes, But I don't think these equations are dependent on whether the circuit is AC or DC right?

Comment: Your first equation has terms representing the voltage across the resistor and the voltage across the capacitor, so you already know the answer!

Comment: @JohnDoty so is my final equation correct?

Comment: @244529 Sure. Just Ohm's law, $V_R=IR$, noting that for a capacitor, $I=C\frac{d}{dt}(V_c)$.